# собственная функция swap, почему и как она работает?

Tags: c++, swap

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    a = b;
    b = a;
}

int main() {

    int x1 = 10, x2 = 20;
    cout << "x1 = " << x1 << ", x2 = " << x2 << endl;
    swap(x1, x2);
    cout << "x1 = " << x1 << ", x2 = " << x2 << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Функция свапает значения, было 10 и 20, стало 20 и 10.
Функция должна принимать два указателя на тип int, а в итоге принимает две переменные типа int, и еще, непонятно почему, работающее тело функции "a = b; b = a", не понимаю, как это работает?

Comment: Для начала уберите `using namespace std;` и убедитесь, что ваша функция [на самом деле не используется](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BJhaQK1DsgrrtyEc). Также см. [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Comment: Ваша функция никак не работает. Как правильно заметил VTT, она вообще не используется в вашем коде.

Comment: Можно не убирать `using...`, а добавить `::` перед `swap`. Этого будет достаточно, чтоб убедиться в некомпилируемости такого вызова nfrjq функции :)

Comment: @Олег Вот поэтому следует избегать всяких using namespace! А лучше отказаться в целом от using

Answer (score 3):

У Вас работает не собственная функция swap, а [функция](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) из стандартной библиотеки std.
Чтобы все заработало, нужно убрать

```
using namespace std;
```

и переделать примерно так

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b; 
    *b = temp;
}

int main() {
    int x1 = 10, x2 = 20;
    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << ", x2 = " << x2 << std::endl;
    swap(&x1, &x2); // Передаём ссылки
    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << ", x2 = " << x2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

В функцию нужно передать ссылки на переменные через оператор &. В самом теле функции нужно выполнить разыменовывание указателя, чтобы получить доступ к значениям.

Comment: Только вот не ссылки, а указатели.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу свой вариант с передачей в ф-ию ссылки(ничего особо не меняется, только вам не нужно будет разыменовывать указатели)

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int &a, int &b);

int main() {
    int x1 = 10, x2 = 20;
    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << ", x2 = " << x2 << std::endl;
    swap(x1, x2);
    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << ", x2 = " << x2 << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void swap(int &a, int &b) {
   int temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}
```